# Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot – Bootloader Question

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10, bootloader

I want to install Ubuntu on my Windows 10 machine. Last time I installed Ubuntu my PC was dead. Both Bootloaders were corrupted. What do I have to choose in the „Select Bootloader“ field? What do I have to do, if Ubuntu does not realize Windows. I saw some videos about dual boot, sometimes it shows: „Install with Windows“. Can I install Ubuntu on the same drive with Windows 10? I have two drives, do you recommend one for Win and one for Linux or is there no problem with two OSs on one drive?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with two OSs running on the same hard drive. This is done through partitioning of the drive.

Usually, the Ubuntu installer detects Windows on it's own.

You have to create partitions for Windows and Ubuntu before beginning the installation of Ubuntu. Meaning, you have to allocate separate amounts of memory for each. Shrink the partition size through Windows disk management to make space for Ubuntu.

It is better to have Windows installed first.

I suggest going through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot in detail.

Comment: The link seems old. It only mentions Master Boot Record (MBR). Modern Windows systems don't have MBR. The bootloader is in the (U)EFI System Partition (ESP).